# How to print a 1 to N without using semicolon ? Explain this code

Tags: c, generic-programming

```
// A recursive C program to print all numbers from 1
// to N without semicoolon 
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10

int main(int num)
{
    if (num <= N && printf("%d ", num) && main(num + 1))
    {
    }     
}
```

How is this program working ?. Please Explain this

Comment: It works poorly, this is horribly written code. It can be simplified by having a sane person writing a loop instead. "without a semicolon" is a useless nonsense requirement.

Comment: and it works very by chance, standard 6.9.1:
*If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: The crap requirements can for example be met by this crap code: `#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10

#define NO_SEMI(expr) if(expr){}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  NO_SEMI(argv[0][0]=0)

  while(argv[0][0]++ < N)
  {
    NO_SEMI(printf("%d\n", argv[0][0]))
  }
}` The sad thing is that this code is much better than the code in the question...

Comment: @tilz0R What about 5.1.2.2.3 ".... reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0."

Comment: @4386427 nice catch. Very stupid standard if we have on 2 completely different chapters similar topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in this awful example relies on some fragile assumptions:

`main` is called with 2 arguments: an `int` representing the number of arguments, including the program name, and an array of `char*` containing the argument string terminated by a `NULL`.

The example assumes that defining `main()` with a single `int` argument will produce code compatible with this calling convention, which may or may not be valid and is explicitly described as having undefined behavior by the C Standard (J.2).

If it is valid or works by chance, the `int` argument received by `main` will be `1` if the program is called from the command line without arguments.

`main()` tests if this argument is `<= N`, is other words if the value is to be printed. If so, it invokes `printf("%d ", num)`, which outputs the decimal representation of `num` to `stdout` and returns the number of characters produced, 2 for the first number, which is non zero, so the code goes on and invokes `main` recursively, passing it the next higher number.

The goes on until all numbers up to `N` have been printed and the first test in the last recursive call fails.

`main` then returns `0` (if the compiler is complies with the C99 or a later standard). Each recursive call returns `0` until the initial call returns `0` to the system.

The code is fragile because `main` is invoked in a non standard way. It would be slightly less ugly to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (num <= N && printf("%d ", num) && main(num + 1, argv)) {}
}
```

Note however that calling `main()` recursively is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: [@Lundin comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875433/how-to-print-a-1-to-n-without-using-semicolon-explain-this-code#comment90703101_51875433) is a counter example to "basically need a recursive function"

Comment: That really does answer the question very well now - thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the function inside returns a value convertable to bool, it will be accepted also called.

> If successful, the total number of characters written is returned. On failure, a negative number is returned.

Above is the return value of printf() function. So yeah `printf("%d ", num)` will always return true in this case and print at each iteration.